# Oracle SQL: How to Sum groups with total of all groups

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

What I am trying to do is basically manufacture a `Sum of sums` that only really makes sense when pivoted.

I am trying to analyze total system degradation, but also see it as `Down` and `Degraded` as separate call outs - this is where I am having trouble. In addition, if there was no value for a given period, it's assumed to be `0`. I am trying to create a fictitious `sum(a) + sum(b)` column and I don't know how to do this

Here is the data, as it exists in the DB, when sum is applied on each category (I've explicitly introduced a year jump, and null values for `impact` are categorized as 'TBD'):

So, summary by week looks like:

| CY | WEEK | IMPACT | DURATION_MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 50 | 2 - Degraded | 175 |
| 2022 | 51 | 1 - Down | 70 |
| 2022 | 51 | 2 - Degraded | 522 |
| 2023 | 1 | 1 - Down | 460 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2 - Degraded | 1258 |
| 2023 | 2 | 1 - Down | 58 |
| 2023 | 2 | 2 - Degraded | 98 |

But, here is what I am shooting for:

| CY | WEEK | 0 - TBD | 2 - Degraded | 1 - Down | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 50 | 0 | 175 | 0 | 175 |
| 2022 | 51 | 0 | 522 | 70 | 592 |
| 2023 | 1 | 0 | 1258 | 460 | 1718 |
| 2023 | 2 | 0 | 98 | 58 | 156 |

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
    cy               INT          NOT NULL,
    week             INT          NOT NULL,
    IMPACT           VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
    duration_minutes NUMBER       NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 50, '2 - Degraded', 42);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 50, '2 - Degraded', 88);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 50, '2 - Degraded', 45);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 51, '1 - Down', 70);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 51, '2 - Degraded', 86);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 51, '2 - Degraded', 220);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2022, 51, '2 - Degraded', 216);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '1 - Down', 29);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '1 - Down', 62);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '1 - Down', 369);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '2 - Degraded', 58);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '2 - Degraded', 42);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '2 - Degraded', 277);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 1, '2 - Degraded', 881);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 2, '1 - Down', 40);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 2, '1 - Down', 18);
INSERT INTO my_table(CY, WEEK, IMPACT, DURATION_MINUTES) VALUES (2023, 2, '2 - Degraded', 98);


commit;
```

And here is the select that produces the unpivoted data:

```sql
SELECT cy,
       week,
       impact,
       SUM(duration_minutes) AS duration_minutes
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY cy, week, impact
 ORDER BY cy, week, impact;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Conditional Sum Aggregation while removing the column `impact` from GROUP BY list such as

```
SELECT cy, week, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN impact IS NULL THEN duration_minutes ELSE 0 END) AS "0 - TBD",
       SUM(CASE WHEN impact = '2 - Degraded' THEN duration_minutes ELSE 0 END) AS "2 - Degraded",
       SUM(CASE WHEN impact = '1 - Down' THEN duration_minutes ELSE 0 END) AS "1 - Down",
       SUM(duration_minutes) AS duration_minutes
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY cy, week
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9CrYD_7A)</kbd>

Comment: WOW! That's way easier then a pivot table. I had assumed there'd be some `coalesce` and `NVL` going on along with a `pivot`

Comment: As I look more at this I realize that this logically reduces to `when it's null,1 or 2, sum duration minutes. Could this be simplified with `group by` ?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Of course you can combine the conditionals as you wish, perhaps I didn't exactly understand what you meant. You might edit the question to rephrase additional cases you wish to ask. If you mean usage of aliases followed by GROUP BY, no, it's not possible in Oracle DB's select statement.